# Tensorflow 2.2.0 error: [Predictions must be > 0] [Condition x >= y did not hold element-wise:] while using Bidirectional LSTM layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I get the following error message when working on a named-entity-recognition task:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  assertion failed: [predictions must be >= 0] [Condition x >= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (bidirectional_lstm_model/time_distributed/Reshape_1:0) = ] [[[-0.100267865 -0.104010895 0.04090859...]]...] [y (Cast_2/x:0) = ] [0]
     [[{{node assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/else/_1/Assert}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_6216]
Function call stack:
train_function
```

How can I troubleshoot this? I have checked my input `train_x` and `train_y` tensors and they seem fine (Some examples provided towards the end).

I was originally using a Conditional Random Field decoder. I replaced that with a Dense layer instead, to see if that changes the error message. The error remains the same though, and is somehow related to the RNN component of the model.

In general, what strategy do you use to troubleshoot such errors deep from within the guts of TF? I tried to set up a debugging session on PyCharm and jumped through a bunch of TF files, without learning anything useful about how to solve my problem.

The following is my network architecture:

```
Model: "bidirectional_lstm_model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
encoder_input (InputLayer)   [(None, None)]            0         
_________________________________________________________________
encoder_embedding (Embedding (None, None, 300)         2013300   
_________________________________________________________________
encoder_bidirectional_rnn (B (None, None, 32)          40576     
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistri (None, None, 25)          825       
=================================================================
Total params: 2,054,701
Trainable params: 41,401
Non-trainable params: 2,013,300
_________________________________________________________________
```

Above + more details (losses, optimizer etc):

```
# Create model
encoder_input = keras.Input(shape=(None,), name='encoder_input')
encoder_embedding = layers.Embedding(input_dim=input_vocabulary,
                                     output_dim=embedding_vector_len,
                                     embeddings_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(embedding_matrix),
                                     trainable=False, name='encoder_embedding')(encoder_input)
encoder_rnn = layers.LSTM(16, return_sequences=True, name='encoder_rnn')
encoder_bidirectional_rnn = layers.Bidirectional(encoder_rnn, name='encoder_bidirectional_rnn')(encoder_embedding)
decoder_dense = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(number_of_tags, name='decoder_dense'))(encoder_bidirectional_rnn)
model = keras.Model(inputs=encoder_input, outputs=decoder_dense, name='bidirectional_lstm_model')
model.summary()

metrics_precision = tf.keras.metrics.Precision()
metrics_recall = tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=[metrics_precision, metrics_recall]
)
```

Here is what my `train_x` and `train_y` arrays look like:

```
# Shapes
train_x.shape  # (9775, 47)  (np.ndarray type)
train_y.shape  # TensorShape([9775, 47, 25])  (Obtained from tf.one_hot)

# Sample (Zero-padded from the right)
train_x[0, :]

# array([4917, 2806, 6357, 2287, 6059,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
#      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
#      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
#      0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
#      0,    0,    0])

train_y[0, :, :]

# array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],  # Non "O" tag
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],  # Non "O" tag
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
#   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you are missing the last layer activation:

```py
decoder_dense = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(number_of_tags, name='decoder_dense'))(encoder_bidirectional_rnn)
```

You should specify that you want a softmax, leaving the activation as default is actually a linear activation, meaning that you can have any value, therefore the negative ones. You should create the last Dense layer as follows:

```py
decoder_dense = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(number_of_tags, activation='softmax', name='decoder_dense'))(encoder_bidirectional_rnn)
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess the error message had me looking too hard at the RNN layer.

Comment: You are right, TensorFlow error messages are usually cryptic.